# Change dropdown value when other fields change

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the essence of the "Rules". If the user has changed this in field of the entity, it should automatically change the value of the field "Stability" (dropdownlist). That is, if the rule had to be changed, then it becomes unstable. Can this be automated?

I wrote a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ChangeStabilityRequirement]
ON [dbo].[Requirement]
After UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
IF (UPDATE(Definition))     
    update [dbo].[Requirement]
    SET  Stability=2;
END;
go
```

**I have a problem**

This trigger set Stability=2, when I change any field.

But I want when field "Stability" set = 2 only when change field "Definition".

Comment: Yes, you can. But to explain how, is too broad I'm afraid.  Do you want to do this clientside? You need to do it serverside anyway. Should the user be able to change the dropdown back to "stable"? Which fields will influence the "stability"? All of them? What have you tried? What does your code look like?

Comment: By default, the "Stability" is set to "middle". If the user changes any other field in essence, that the "stability" should be "Low".
I do not know how to do it.

Comment: What I must to put the code? Controller, model, views?